# Event handling on images displayed in datagrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I have a dojo datagrid displaying records. I am displaying image [image] on each row. On click of the image, a request to delete the record should sent to the server. I am setting structure to the grid in Js class file. I have formatted the column to display the image as below.

```
GridStructure= [
   {
    name: "Name",
    field: "Name",
    width: "100px",
    rowSelector : '20px'
    },
{
    name: '',
    width: '20px',
    field: "",
    formatter: function(inValue) {
        this.customStyles.push("vertical-align:middle");
        return "<img src='images/delete.jpg'/>";
    }
}]
```

how should I handle the onclick event of image and call another JS method which will pass the row details to the business layer for further processing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working but with a twist. Instead of writing event handling on images, I wrote it on the cell holding that image. So that way I get all the details about row index, the data in the row, everything. that served my purpose. :)